# Is shared assembly the only way to create objects from WCF REST service

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-client

I am writing an application that is consuming an in-house WCF-based REST service and I'll admit to being a REST newbie.  Since I can't use the "Add Service Reference", I don't have ready-made proxy objects representing the return types from the service methods.  So far the only way I've been able to work with the service is by sharing the assembly containing the data types exposed by the service.

My problem with this arrangment is that I see only two possibilities:

1. Implement DTOs (DataContracts) and expose those types from my service. I would still have to share an assembly but this approach would limit the types contained in the assembly to the service contract and DTOs.  I don't like to use DTOs just for the sake of using them, though as they add another layer of abstraction and processing time to convert from domain object to DTO and vice versa.  Plus, if I want to have business rules, validation, etc. on the client, I'd have to share the domain objects anyways, so is the added complexity necessary.
2. Support serialization of my domain objects, expose those types and share that assembly.  This would allow me to share business and validation logic with the client but it also exposes parts of my domain objects to the client that are meant only for the service app.

Perhaps an example would help the discussion...

- My client application will display a list of documents that is obtained from the REST service (a GET operation). The service returns an array of DocumentInfo objects (lightweight, read-only representation of a Document).
- When the user selects one of the items, the client retrieves the full Document object from the REST service (GET by id) and displays a data entry form so the user can modify the object.  We would want validation rules for a rich user experience.
- When the user commits the changes, the Document object is submitted to the REST service (a PUT operation) where it is persisted to the back-end data store.
- If the state of the Document allows, the user may "Publish" the Document. In this case, the client POSTs a request to the REST service with the Document.ID value and the service performs the operation by retrieving the server-side Document domain object and calling the Publish method.  The Publish method should not be available to the client application.

As I see it, my Document and DocumentInfo objects would have to be in a shared assembly.  Doing this makes Document.Publish available to the client.  One idea to hide it would be to make the method internal and add an InternalsVisibleTo attribute that allows my service app to call the method and not the client but this seems "smelly."

Am I on the right track or completely missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classes you use on the server should not be the same classes you use on the client (apart from during the data transfer itself).  The best approach is to create a package (assembly/project) containing DTOs, and share these between the server and the client.  You did mention that you don't want to create DTO's *for the sake of it*, but it is best practice.  The performance impact of adding extra layers is negligible, and layering actually helps make your application easier to develop and maintain (avoiding situations like yours where the client has access to server code).

I suggest starting with the following packages:

1. Service: Resides on server only, exposes the service and contains server application logic.
2. DTO: Resides on both server and client.  Contains simple classes which contain data which need to be passed between server and client.  Classes have no code apart from properties.  These are short lived objects which survive long enough only to transfer data.
3. Repository: Resides on client only.  Calls the server, and turns Model objects into DTO's (and vice versa).
4. Model: Resides on client only. Contains classes which represent business objects and relationships.  Model objects stay in memory throughout the life of the application.

Your client application code should call into Repository to get Model objects (you might also consider looking into MVVM if your not sure how to go about this).

If your service code is sufficiently complex that it needs access to Model classes, you should create a separate Model package (obviously give it a different name) - the only classes which should exist both on server and client are DTO classes.

Comment: Since when is it considered best practice to use DTOs with REST?  REST transfers media types across the wire, not objects.

Comment: Obviously it's been awhile for any activity on this post, but one question has been nagging me - what do you mean by "media types"?

Answer (score 2):

I thought that I'd post the approach I took while giving credit to both Greg and Jake for helping guide me down the path.

While Jake is correct that deserializing the data on the client can be done with any type as long as it implements the same data contract, enforcing this without WSDL can be a bit tricky.  I'm in an environment where other developers will be working with my solution both to support and maintain the existing as well as creating new clients that consume my service.  They are used to "Add Service Reference" and going.

Greg's points about using different objects on the client and the server were the most helpful. I was trying to minimize duplicate by sharing my domain layer between the client and the server and that was the root of my confusion.  As soon as I separated these into two distinct applications and looked at them in isolation, each with their own use cases, the picture became clearer.

As a result, I am now sharing a Contracts assembly which contains my service contracts so that a client can easily create a channel to the server (using WCF on the client-side) and data contracts representing the DTOs passed between client and service.

On the client, I have ViewModel objects which wrap the Model objects (data contracts) for the UI and use a service agent class to communicate with the service using the service contracts from the shared assembly.  So when the user clicks the "Publish" button in the UI, the controller (or command in WPF/SL) calls the Publish method on the service agent passing in the ID of the document to publish.  The service agent relays the request to the REST API (Publish operation).

On the server, the REST API is implemented using the same service contracts. In this case, the service works with my domain services, repositories and domain objects to carry out the tasks.  So when the Publish service operation is invoked, the service retrieves the Document domain object from the DocumentRepository, calls the Publish method on the object which updates the internal state of the object and then the service passes the updated object to the Update method of the repository to persist the changes.

I am pleased with the outcome as I believe this gives me a more robust and extensible architecture to work with.  I can change the ViewModels as needed to support the UI with no concern over poluting the service(s) and, likewise, change the internal implementation of the service operations (domain layer) without affecting the client application(s).  All that binds the two are the contracts they share.  Pretty clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your domain objects and then de-serialize them into different types on the client. Both types need to implement the same data contract. All serializable types have at least a default data contract that includes all public read/write properties and fields.